# Error al conectar crystal reports con servidor

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación en visual basic 2017 que se conecta a SQL, el problema viene cuando ejecuto el .exe en la maquina del cliente y deseo generar un informe 
cabe destacar que el programa se conecta al a la base de datos que esta en el servidor perfectamente, el problema es únicamente con el reporte
este es el error que tira

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código que utilizo

```
Dim Reporte As New rpt_Reporte_Procesadas

            Dim boConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo
            boConnectionInfo.ServerName = "10.130.XX.XXX"
            boConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Base_datos"
            boConnectionInfo.UserID = "Admin"
            boConnectionInfo.Password = "XXXXXX"
            boConnectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL
            For Each t As Table In Reporte.Database.Tables
                Dim boTableLogOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo = t.LogOnInfo
                boTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = boConnectionInfo
                t.ApplyLogOnInfo(boTableLogOnInfo)
            Next
```

lo que me parece extraño es que no establece el nombre de la base de datos y a la hora del mensaje tampoco me deja escribir en ese campo, creo que el problema va por ahí

Gracias de antemano

Comment: instala Client Native SQL 2012

Answer (score 2):

Listo pude resolver mi problema, la solución es cambiar el tipo de conexión del reporte a Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server.
En mi caso lo que hice fue crear un nuevo reporte pero con esa nueva conexión 
dejo imágenes de donde se realiza

En el mismo reporte sigue estos pasos

[image: En el Mismo reporte]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que les ayude la solución